# Poisson - P(A | B)

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose we have a Poisson random variable X with $\lambda = 0.06$. $X$ Denotes the number of failures per attempt for a given game

Suppose player A has two attempts at the game. I want to find the probability that both attempts lead to failures.

My attempt:

As they have had two attempts our lambda is $\lambda = 0.12$. Is the required probability then $P(X = 2)?$ What I am struggling with here is that in reality I am trying to find the probability that each game is a failure so my approach doesn't feel right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of failures per attempt is distributed as $Poisson(0.06)$ then the probability of any failures is $P(X>0)=1-P(X=0)=1-\frac{(0.06)^0e^{-0.06}}{0!}=1-e^{-0.06}$

If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent attempts at the game then P(both attempts lead to failures)=P($X_1>1$ and $X_2>1$)=P($X_1>1$)P($X_2>1$)=$(1-e^{-0.06})^2$.